# How to compute the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n^2-1)^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to compute a limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n^2-1)^n}$? My idea was to approximate $\frac{1}{(n^2-1)^n}$ with $\frac{1}{n^{2n}}$ since the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{(n^2-1)^n}}{\frac{1}{n^{2n}}} = 1$, meaning that they "behave" the same, but $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{2n}}$ I still don't know how to compute, since in the denominator is the indeterminate form of $\infty^{\infty}$.

Comment: The limit is not undetermined here. $(n^2-1)^n$ goes "pretty fast" to infinity

Comment: Isn't that $\infty^{\infty}$?

Comment: if you take something very big and positive, and elevate it to something very big and positive, what do you think will happen?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$0\le \frac1{(n^2-1)^n}\le \frac1n$$

Comment: Congratulations, Sami!